# How to get a count of every single element in an xml file using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've tried a bunch of queries using two xml files; one is the copy of the other. After removing a child of a child in one doc, I still get the same count when getting all elements. Can someone give an example of getting every single element in an xml file (siblings, children, etc) and returning the count? I just want to know how many elements are in the file. I don't need to filter or get values.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(yourDocumentPath);
var nbOfElements = xDoc.Descendants().Count();
```

Comment: Oops, found a defect in my test code which was doing exactly what you suggested. But thanks for confirming that I was going it right!